# Regarding Guideline 1.3 - Safety - Kids Category App Rejection

Tags: ios, objective-c

My iOS App is in the Kids category and i am using below firebase pods for Pushotification and Chat functionality.

> pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '~> 4.1'
> pod 'FirebaseDatabase', '~> 6.1'
> pod 'FirebaseAuth', '~> 6.6'

I am getting rejection of my App in AppStore because of Guideline 1.3 - Safety - Kids Category

Suggest me is this because of firebase SDK i am using?

**Below is the rejection statement from Apple.**

> Guideline 1.3 - Safety - Kids Category
>
> We continue to find that your Kids Category app includes analytics,
> advertising and collects, transmits, or has the ability to share
> personal information or device information with third parties.
>
> Your app includes the following feature(s), contrary to guideline 1.3
> of the App Store Review Guidelines:
>
> Third-party analytics or third-party advertising with the ability to
> collect, transmit or share identifiable information, including, for
> example, IDFA.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please remove this functionality or revise your
> app so that no personally identifiable information or device
> information is sent to third parties.

Comment: did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**. As written here: "To resolve this issue, please remove this functionality or revise your app so that no personally identifiable information or device information is sent to third parties."

It is not about the Firebase